# Numeric field of type Calculated column will show extra decimal places with values of 99999

Tags: development, list-view, column, calculated-column

I am working on a sharepoint server 2016. and i have a custom list with the following fields:-

[image]

i am showing sample of a test data with a test column names, as these info is somehow confidential.

now as shown in the above picture, i am getting a value of  `-6,999,95999999`, which is a result of the following calcualtion:-

```
(5250 * 12 * 1) - (5833.33 * 12 * 1 )
```

now using the calculator on my windows machine, the result will be `-6999.96` .. so why inside my sharepoint calculated column  i am getting `-6,999,95999999` instead??
also if i change the number `5833.33` to `4833.33` i will get a correct result without extra decimals as follow:-

[image]

which is the result of the following equation :-

```
(5250 * 12 * 1) - (4833.33 * 12 * 1 )
```

so is there a way to avoid unwanted decimals and why there are showing on certain scenarios only? keeping in mind that all the numeric fields i am using and all the calculated columns are of type numeric and have automatic number of decimals..

Comment: Did you select number field type for your calculated  column? This is where you can control the decimal.

Comment: @SMerchant as i mentioned before all the calculated columns i am using  are of type numeric with automatic decimal points... now i do not want to control the decimals ,, as users can enter the number of decimals they like (this is the business requirment).. but i want the result of my equation to be equal to the number i am getting from my windows machine calculator.. or the calculator i use when i was in the high school or the result i get from excel !!! is this something SP can not deliver out of the box !!! and it should show extra 9999 decimals ?

Comment: Yes, users can enter the decimal in the fields, but calculated fields are auto calculating based on the input so you can control the decimal points.  I tested your numbers and I get the desired results.

Comment: It is not SP failing.. it's the CPU .. type ``0.1+0.2`` in the F12 Console. If the CPU can't calculated then how on earth can an Application like SharePoint running on that CPU? Excel IS a Calculator programmed to deal with all CPU flaws, SP is not a Calculator, not a Database, it is a CMS, so you have to do more correction work yourself... with the TEXT function

Comment: @SMerchant and what is the desired results which you get?? you did not get 99999 decimals ?

Comment: I get -6,999.96

Comment: @SMerchant so are you using numeric numbers which have automatic decimal point ??

Comment: @SMerchant can you advice if you used Numeric fields with automatic decimal points ?

Comment: I have a column A and B (numeric with auto decimal).  I have a calculated field with the formula returning number with decimal point 2 (A * 12 * 1) - (B * 12 * 1 ) = 6,999.96.  Since users are not entering any data on the calculated field you can control the decimal points.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @johnG did you manage to get this working?

Comment: @S merchant not really ..any ideas from ur side??

Comment: ♦ If an answer was helpful could you remove your question from the SO unanswered list, by marking it as answered, tnx

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard TEXT function to format a Number anyway you want

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/TEXT-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB

Comment: thanks for the reply.. now i do not want to manually format the calculated columns ..now the calculated columns i am using  are of type numeric with automatic decimal points.. now i do not want to control the decimals ,, as users can enter the number of decimals they like (this is the business requirment). but i want the result of my equation to be equal to the number i am getting from my windows machine calculator or the result i get from excel !!! is this something SP can not deliver out of the box !!! and it should show extra 9999 decimals ?

Comment: John, again..and again.. if people say to you to **use technology X** then (considering their SP experience) there most of the time is **no technology Y**.. I once wanted SP to turn my Wife into Catherina Zeta Jones... didn't happen... blamed SharePoint for a years... then learned to live with the fact SharePoint is a 15+ year old dinosaur. So I am now learning AWS (Amazon) and hope for a better future

Comment: and what about the problem i am facing ? i do not want to format any numeric values.. as we want users to enter whatever numbers and number of decimals  they want .. i am not talking about old/new technology.. now if i do the equation on my solar calculator which goes back to 20 years i will get correct results without 9999 decimals...

Comment: I don't know your wife, so I can tell what your problem is (but by your responses I acknowledge your problems in this area). For SharePoint: What you get is what you get. And it is not SharePoint... it is computers in general... just typ ``0.1 + 0.2`` in a JavaScript console. Your 20 year old calculator doesn't have a 64 Bit Processor optimized to do important calculations fast and thus gets sloppy on edge-cases

Comment: @Dannu but how i can use the txt functions ,, baring in mind that users can enter whatever number of decimals they want ??? i am not sure how i can control it ?